# How to centralize a div with pictures

Tags: css, reactjs

I am totally a newbie when it comes to coding.
I have a div with 4 pictures in it. I want the div to be centralize but I can´t make it happen. If I manage to centralize, they are not aligned any more (horizontal). How do I do this?
I´ve tried everything, justify-content, display, position, align-items and so on. Where do I go wrong?

[What code do I use to put the boxes in the center, just as they are, horizontal?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckP7l.jpg)

Thanks for you´re help!

Comment: Plz share the code.

Comment: always share the code you are working on, not pictures.

Comment: here is how I do it. 
put a wrapper div and give it a class of container  
`.container{
width:100%;
display:flex; 
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {border: 1px solid #678596; max-width: 350px; margin: 30px auto;} 
      
.parentClass { display: flex;  justify-content:center;}
      
.parentClass div {margin: 5px; background: #678596; width: 50px; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center; font-size: 30px; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="parentClass">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>

</div>
```